# comma separated Lyx Ieeetran bibliography citations

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, citing, natbib, ieeetran

How do you setup Lyx with the ieeetran template to produce citations that are comma separated?

for instance:  "foo is reported to be bar percent in [1,2,3]".

or equivalently: "foo is reported to be bar percent in [1-3]".

I have done what is recommended in this forum posting:

http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=8763

Also, I am able to get comma separated citations when I select:

Document>settings>bibliography: natbib and with natbib style set to "numerical". However, other issues creep up using natbib that display an awful "(author?)" tag right before the citation as was reported in:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/70862
http://osdir.com/ml/editors.lyx.general/2003-12/msg00015.html

This isn't resolved by changing the bibliography style from ieeetran to ieeetranN or ieeetranSN, ect..

Does anyone have a general crash course for how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: put `\usepackage{cite}` in the preamble, along
with the following definitions:
`\renewcommand\citepunct{,}
\renewcommand\citedash{--}`.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a WYSIWYG answer.

Comment: not necessary for this to be WYSIWYG. Works, thank you and happy new year!